# I want to locate an element in linkedin DOM for add new education section (plus sign)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to find the Xpath of (plus sign) in linkedin profile in adding new education field as per screenshot

[image: element_to_find]

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[contains(@aria-label,'Add new education')]")).click();
```

but an error massage found that:

> Unable to locate element

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//li-icon[@aria-label ='Add new education']")).click();
```

Note: if you are still not able to locate the element then probably you are trying to access the webelement even before it is loaded on the webpage.
In that case you need to use

```
//30 is the wait time in seconds.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

//This will wait for 30 seconds to locate the element before throwing an Exception.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//li-icon[@aria-label ='Add new education']")));
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here is the locator to identify the `+` in education.

**Using CSS** `a[class$='add-education ember-view']`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class$='add-education ember-view']")).click();
```

**xpath** `//a[contains(@class,'add-education ember-view')]`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'add-education ember-view')]")).click();
```